# Swift custom framework - Merge-module command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, clang

As we've created our own Swift based framework, build it and deploy it into the master project, the following error occurs:

[image]

By importing the framework we are however able to use all of the publicly declared methods and classes. But, when building the project, the error as shown at the screenshot appears.

Any hind what the problem might be?

Comment: please have you found the solution? i have the same problem really a nightmare thanks

Comment: cleaning solution sometimes helps -> will show the correct error

Answer (score 7):

Check your swift bridging header (`Project-Bridging-Header.h`) for problems;  You might be importing an Obj-c header that doesn't exist, etc.

This was the case for me with that exact same error.

Comment: Worked for me too, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just used the Clean Build Folder command (command + shift + k), and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I built framework in iOS and used it in tvOS Project. that caused me to find out this issue.

Build separate frameworks for iOS, tvOS .. Issue fixed with this approach

Answer (score 0):

For me I had a method in Objective C that returns `(nullable UIImage *)` ,changing it to `(UIImage *)` fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, cleaning build folder solved the problem.